# How do I pass argument from NavHost to ViewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, jetpack-compose-navigation

Could you please help me? How can I pass the argument from NavHost and get it in ViewModel?
I found a solution using SavedStateHandle but it doesn't work.

```
@HiltViewModel

class NewsScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(
    val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
) : ViewModel() {

  private val _sourceStatus = MutableStateFlow(savedStateHandle.get("source") ?: null)
    val getSourceStatus: StateFlow<String> get() = _sourceStatus

    private val _internetStatus = MutableStateFlow(ConnectivityObserver.Status.UNAVAILABLE)
    val internetStatus: StateFlow<ConnectivityObserver.Status> get() = _internetStatus

  private val _sourceStatus = MutableStateFlow(savedStateHandle.get("source") ?: FeedSource.NEXTWEB.sourceString )
    val getSourceStatus: StateFlow<String> get() = _sourceStatus
```

NavHost looks like this. During the debug process I founnd out that there is a value coming to source variable but not retrieved in ViewModel.

```
NavHost(navController = navController, startDestination = Screens.NewsScreen.route) {

    composable(
        route = "news/{source}",
        arguments = listOf(
            navArgument("source") {
                type = NavType.StringType
                defaultValue = ""
            }
        )
    ) { backStackEntry ->
       val source = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("source") ?: "nullsource"
        NewsScreen(viewModel = newsScreenViewModel, navController = navController, paddingValues = paddingValues)
    }
```

This is a section for bottom navigation. When I navigate from one tab to another it should pass an argument.

```
@Composable
fun BottomNavigationSection(navController: NavHostController, items: List<Screens>) {
    BottomNavigation {
        val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
        val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route
        items.forEach { screen ->
            BottomNavigationItem(
                modifier = Modifier.background(colorResource(id = R.color.grey))
                    .fillMaxSize() ,
                icon = {
                    Icon(
                        painterResource(id = screen.icon),
                        contentDescription = screen.route,
                    )
                },
                selected = currentRoute == screen.route,
                onClick = {
                    if (currentRoute != screen.route) {
                        navController.navigate(screen.route)
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `NewsScreen` should get its view model from `hiltViewModel()` function:

```
@Composable
fun NewsScreen(
    viewModel: NewsScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    //...
)
```

And not injected manually:

```
//...
NewsScreen(/*viewModel = newsScreenViewModel,*/ navController = navController, paddingValues = paddingValues)
//...
```

Comment: When I do like this I get a new instance of ViewModel each time I navigate to certain screen.

Comment: That is because of your `BottomNavigation` implementation that adds a new destination to the navigation stack each time you navigate with it. Also, the way you init `MutableStateFlow` with the argument would only work once per `ViewModel` instance. Would it be OK for your app to have a shared state that you could read and change from every screen instead of passing arguments through navigation, or do you want to recreate each screen with its `ViewModel` each time you navigate to it? @Alex20280

Comment: Right now I have a problem with passing arguments between bottom navigation screens. It's preferable to have separate ViewModels instead of Shared one.

Comment: You can have a separate `ViewModel` for each screen and a shared one. Bottom navigation implies free navigation between several screens, not a linear flow where each screen depends on some data passed from the previous destination. I think shared ViewModel would be a good fit. @Alex20280

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by passing argument to the composable function parameter

In the `NavHost`:

```
    composable(route = "news/{source}") { backStackEntry ->
       val source = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString("source") ?: "nullsource"
        NewsScreen(
            viewModel = newsScreenViewModel, 
            source = source, // pass argument to the screen function
            navController = navController, 
            paddingValues = paddingValues
        )
    }
```

Add `source` to your composable screen and handle changes:

```
@Composable
fun NewsScreen(..., source: String) {
        LaunchedEffect(key1 = source) {
              viewModel.setSource(source)
        }
}
```

In the ViewModel add `setSource(source: String)` function and save the source value:

```
    private val _source = MutableStateFlow("")

    fun setSource(source: String) {
        // This check is necessary because when you press the "back" button, 
        // the value of the argument passed to the screen will be equal to zero
        if (_source.value != source) _source.value = id 
    }
```

BTW, it's better to pass only lambda functions to your nested composables, so you don't need to pass the `NavHostController` to the `BottomNavigationSection` function, only the onClick lambda is needed.

It will be good for composable previews and for code readability. You can move logic with navigation to the NavHost and pass navigation lambdas to the screen.